# Invalid property 'driverClass' of bean class [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource] for org.postgresql.Driver

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa, postgresql-9.1

I am trying to use JPA SpringData Framework with Hibernate and PSQL, stuck on this  mistake
stackoverflow wants me to write here smt
stackoverflow wants me to write here smt
stackoverflow wants me to write here smt
stackoverflow wants me to write here smt
stackoverflow wants me to write here smt

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:94)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [META-INF/ApplicationContext.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'driverClass' of bean class [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource]: Bean property 'driverClass' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'driverClass' of bean class [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource]: Bean property 'driverClass' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1076)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:927)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1510)
    ... 44 more
```

here is my ApplicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">
    <!-- database -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClass" value="org.postgresql.Driver"></property>
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/journey"></property>
        <property name="user" value="postgres"></property>
        <property name="password" value="canada"></property>
    </bean>
    <!-- entity Manager -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="MAP"/>
    </bean>
    <!-- Transaction Manager -->
    <bean id="myTransactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>
    <!-- JPA package -->
    <jpa:repositories base-package="home.map.events.dao"></jpa:repositories>

</beans>
```

If anyone has any suggestions please comment the post
Thank you

Comment: Post your config details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It claims that `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource` doesn't have a property called `driverClass` because `DriverManagerDataSource` only has the property `driverClassName`.

Checkout the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DriverManagerDataSource.html#setDriverClassName-java.lang.String-)

So you should change the line to:

```
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"></property>
```

Comment: well, now it says 'org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'dataSource' of bean class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Bean property 'dataSource' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?'

Comment: never mind, it is now resolved, I changed to '<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">'
Thank you